# parsing pattern using logparse gork not working

Tags: regex, telegraf, logparser

I have a log file with a specific pattern format and I want to extract some field using a pattern but still not able to retrieve the correct value :

This's a line of my log file :

```
2021-02-08 09:09:38,111 INFO  [stdout] (default task-26) Payload: {"rqUID":"12345678-abdcABCD-09876543-abcdefgh","addUsrIdentif":{"userId":"string","requestDate":"string","userLanguage":"string","financialInstitution":"string","products":["string"],"providerLogin":"string","providerPasswd":"string"},"customerInformation":{"customerId":"string","orgId":"string","orgDepth":12,"contractId":"string"},"merchantInformation":{"chainId":"string","merchantId":"string","posId":"string"},"agentInformation":{"oedInstitutionId":"string","branchId":"string","agentId":"string"},"caseReference":12}
```

I want to extract the field **rqUID** value using this pattern I get this result :

```
[[inputs.logparser]]
    files = ["D:\\server.log"]
    from_beginning = true
    [inputs.logparser.grok]
        measurement = "PWCAPI"
        patterns = ["%{LOG_PATTERN}"]
        custom_patterns = '''
        LOG_PATTERN %{WORD:rqUID}
'''
```

Results :

{
"rqUID": [
[
"2021"
]
]
}

My purpose is the get : `rqUID = 12345678-abdcABCD-09876543-abcdefgh`
I tested the pattern using : https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Can someone help ,thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a named capturing group here with a customized pattern:

```php
"rqUID":"(?<rqUID>[^"]+)
```

**Details**:

- `"rqUID":"` - a literal substring
- `(?<rqUID>[^"]+)` - a named capturing group `rqUID` that captures any one or more chars other than a `"` char.

Comment: It's work on the online editor but still have probleme when added to my telegraf custom_pattern  LOG_PATTERN %{"rqUID":"(?<rqUID>[^"]+):rqUID}

Comment: @e2rabi You are not doing it correctly since it should not be wrapped with `%{...}`, this syntax is for named patterns. You just need `LOG_PATTERN "rqUID":"(?<rqUID>[^"]+)`. The named capturing group name sets the field name, you do not any additional construct here.